# Register external @AspectJ aspects dynamically in main spring project

Tags: aspectj, autowired, autoproxy

I'm currently tying to integrate external @AspectJ aspects into a Spring+JSF project. That is, my aspects are implemented in seperate projects and should be loaded into the main application context at runtime. This is working fine if I declare the external aspect in my application context which is then loaded first thing in my main.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
```

However, I want to be able to load an unknown number of Aspects dynamically so I can package some aspects into plugins that get deployed depending on dependency settings in my maven pom.

here's my app-context:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd  
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd  
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="..." />

    <import resource="app-ds-jpa.xml"/>

    <!-- a explicit -->
    <bean id="stopWatchProviderAspect" class="....util.StopWatchProviderAspect" />      
    <!-- b dynamic -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator" /> 

    <!-- Enable the @AspectJ support -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
</beans>
```

StopWatchProvider is loaded via a maven dependency. Defining the bean explicitly (a) will work fine. The dynamic approach however fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultData': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ....manager.CustomerManager ....util.DefaultData.customerManager; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ....manager.CustomerManager field ....util.DefaultData.customerManager to $Proxy26
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at ....App.main(App.java:190)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ....manager.CustomerManager ....util.DefaultData.customerManager; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ....manager.CustomerManager field ...e.util.DefaultData.customerManager to $Proxy26
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ....manager.CustomerManager field ....util.DefaultData.customerManager to $Proxy26
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498)
```

Don't know if that's even possible. However I found in an [old post](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2703) in the comments, that the AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator conflicts with my Autowireing byName.

Found somewhere else, that this kind of error suggests, I am proxying a proxy which is illegal, though I don't understand what that's supposed to mean.

One answer to a [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390556/aspectj-and-spring-with-aspectj-autoproxy) is, that I need to do the autoproxy after all bean initialization but that didn't help (as seen in my app-context)

I've been looking around forever for a way to autodetect my Aspects in a main application without having to staticly define them in the main app-context.xml
I don't need to do this via the AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator. As long as I don't have to "register" all aspects in the one app-context.xml file I am happy.

My alternative would be to have all plugins implement a common interface "Pluggable" with access to a PluginManager via which they could get start()ed, loading up their own application context so that I can put the bean definition in their child context .xml as a resource within their respective projects. I kind of got this to work (at least the loading of several application contexts so I can keep the bean information in the corresponging package) but I'd still prefer a more dynamic approach.

Thanks for any pointers or maybe even answers to why I get that exception!

---

**EDIT:**

Since no one seems to know a solution for the conflict between autowire by name and `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` we register our aspects inside their project's context now and import all project contexts into the web app that uses the aspect:

**Core Project**:

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect { ... }
```

core-context.xml:

```
<bean id="someAspect" class="path.to.core.SomeAspect />         
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

**Web Project**:

```
<import resource="classpath:core-context.xml"/>
```

Then the aspect will fire in the web project as well. This suffices for us for now.

I guess another dynamic approach would be to scan the classpath for `@Aspect` annotations inside a setup bean and register the aspects via a BeanFactory.

Still, if anyone knows more about the conflict between `Autowire: by-name` and `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` please share it.